# Retrieve GMSPlace instance from user defaults

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I know we cannot save custom classes to `UserDefaults`. But it would be very convenient in my code to save a GMSPlace instance to userdefaults and retrieve it.

Ideally, I would like come up with the following functions :

```
func save(selectedPlace: GMSPlace) {}
func getSelectedPlace() -> GMSPlace? {}
```

I suppose I should convert it to NSData or transform it into a dictionary. I went for the second option but I don't know how to retrieve a GMSPlace instance out of a dictionary. In other words, for now, I know only how to do this :

```
func save(selectedPlace: GMSPlace) {}
func getSelectedPlace() -> [String: Any]? {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't save GMSPlace in userdefault because of GMSPlace class not confirm to NSEncoding & NSDecoding protocols.

But can achive this by creating a NSDictionary with all parameters from GMSPlace class and save that newly create NSDictionary to NSUserdefaults.

And when you access agian then get the dictinary from NSUserdefault and create the GMSPlace class object.

Let us know if you have any query in implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think it's the right answer. Even if I hope for a simpler one :) Now encoding protocols are clearer to me at least

Comment: For the record, I finally chose to implement my own Place class that uses only the properties that I need from GMSPlace (very few). I then implement NSCoding for this class. I find it more elegant. And also it allows me to abstract GMSPlace all over the code which will come in handy in case GMaps SDK evolves or if I want to switch to another map service.